# Cant get dplyr & RCurl to work on ubuntu 13.10 (or 12.04)

Tags: r, ubuntu, rcurl, dplyr

I am running 13.10 AWS instance, with shiny-server on it. I've successfully installed various packages into R version 3.0.3, and r-base-dev but I am struggling to install dplyr and RCurl.

```
* installing *source* package ‘shiny’ ...
* DONE (shiny)
> library(shiny)
>
```

but when I try install dplyr

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-162:/$ sudo su - \
>     -c "R -e \"install.packages('dplyr', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""

R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) -- "Warm Puppy"

> install.packages('dplyr', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘assertthat’, ‘BH’

* installing *source* package ‘assertthat’ ...
* DONE (assertthat)
* installing *source* package ‘BH’ ...
* DONE (BH)
* installing *source* package ‘dplyr’ ...
** package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-    library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"   -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
xg++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 4
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/dplyr’
```

while when I try manual

```
> install.packages("dplyr", repos="/home/ubuntu/dplyr_0.1.3.tar.gz")
Installing package into '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository /home/ubuntu/dplyr_0.1.3.tar.gz/src/contrib
Warning message:
package 'dplyr' is not available (for R version 3.0.3)
```

and when I unpackage dplyr

```
> install.packages("dplyr", repos="/home/ubuntu/dplyr")
Installing package into '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository /home/ubuntu/dplyr/src/contrib
Warning message:
package 'dplyr' is not available (for R version 3.0.3)
```

and I also have issue with RCurl, curl is installed on Ubuntu

```
> ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-162:/$ sudo su -\ -c "R -e \"install.packages('RCurl', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) -- "Warm Puppy"

> install.packages('RCurl', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...
** package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for curl-config... no
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RCurl’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RCurl", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/") :
installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
```

while on manual install, same errors as with dplyr.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I solve this issue? I also tried running Rstudio instance on AWS but they only have R 3.0.1 which does not support dplyr.

Comment: Regarding RCurl: try `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev`

Comment: See [this](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/FAQ.html) for `RCurl`. `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` is recommended but AFAIK @EDi's version will work as well

Comment: Ok, I will report results.

Comment: To install `dplyr` or any other package from the command line you just need to say `R CMD INSTALL /path/to/package`. R does not understand your `repos`. Give what you are giving in `repos` to `pkgs` and `repos=NULL`. Having said that you seem to be getting a compiler error for which you should submit a bug report or seek help on dplyr's mailing list (if any).

Comment: Ok, this worked out well for RCurl. Thank You. But I used R CMD INSTALL and still get same error, will report it on github now.

Comment: I reported the issue https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/349, but I dont get what Hadley is saying. Anyone has an idea what I did wrong, and how to use standard complier? I am running regular AWS images.